# Listing Comport in jComboBox

Tags: java, serial-port, jcombobox, enumeration

[image: Debug]I am trying to populate a jComboBox with a list of the available Comports in my system.  Below is how i have tried to implement this but when i click on the ComboBox is is still empty.  Is this used in the correct context as an ActionPerformed?

```
public void comPortcomboBoxActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        Enumeration portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();


        while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
          CommPortIdentifier cpi = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();

          if (cpi.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
            comPortcomboBox.setEnabled(true);
            comPortcomboBox.addItem(cpi.getName());
            resultsTextArea.setText(cpi.getName());
            }


          }
     }
```

Comment: Why don't you put a breakpoint in your code and check if `CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers()` returns any values?

Comment: I am new to this so i had to go away and learn about Debugging,  I put a breakpoint in but nothing happened.  When i initially start the application in Debug i get the attached happen

Comment: Ah, I see. The ActionPerformed listener is called when you select an item from the combobox. Since you don't have any items, it will not be called. You probably need to run this code in the constructor of your component.

Comment: Fantastic,  That cracked it.  It drastically increased the time it takes to open the app though.  Can you suggest a method of populating the list after the rest of the GUI has loaded?

Comment: Hi Patrick another tip is only set the comPortCombobox to enabled once.
And if i understand what is happening remove the resultsTextArea as well. Since your dumping a portion of your work during construction to screen this slows down drasticly

Comment: Hi Blaatz0r, That was my primitive attempt at debugging before asking the question so i will remove it.  Thanks for the tips.